# Why is the potential inside a hollow metal spherical shell with a point charge $q$ at the center equal to $kq/r+kq/b-kq/a$ rather than $kq/r$?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electrostatics, electric-fields, potential, conductors

I'm reading Section 20-6 of *Tipler's Physics for Scientists and Engineers*, where the potential in and around a hollow conducting spherical shell (inner radius $a$, outer radius $b$) with a point charge $q$ at the center is derived. I agree with the derivations for in the surface of the shell and outside the shell.

$$V = \begin{cases}kq/r, & r \gt b \\ kq/b, &a \lt r \lt b\end{cases}$$

Now because the potential is constant across a conductor, $V(a)$ should be equal to $V(b)$. However, Tipler ignores this in their derivation.

Their final solution is:
$$V = \frac{kq}{r} + \frac{kq}{b} - \frac{kq}{a} \;\text{for}\; r \lt a$$

I believe it should be $V = kq/r$ since the potentials at b and a are equivalent. Furthermore, this makes intuitive sense to me, as the potential is then treated as if the shell were just a point charge.
Am I missing a point of nuance?

Comment: Shouldn't the second condition be $b>r>a$?

Comment: Yes, it should be. Good catch.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Potential energy is well-defined only up to an additive constant. We usually set the convention $V(r=\infty)=0$ to remove this degree of freedom; that's certainly what Tipler did here. This convention demands $V=kq/r$ for $r>b$, but only because this region includes the $r\to\infty$ limit. The best Gauss's law now tells us for $r<a$ is $V=kq/r+C$, where $C$ is no longer a free choice of convention; it's fixed by the continuity of $V$. Since $V$ is constant for $r<a<b$, therein $V=kq/b$ to ensure continuity at $r=b$. Tipler's $r<a$ formula, which surprised you, achieves continuity at $r=a$ with $r<a$ behaviour $V(a)=kq/b,\,C=kq(1/b-1/a)$. This result is the same *up to an additive constant* as that region would see without a conductor, i.e. the electric field strength $-dV/dr$ is the same; the additive constant needn't bother us, since it's a result of our convention.